# hadoop start-dfs having issues (no file)

Tags: linux, hadoop

when I run start-dfs.sh, the route of server3 is `/home/xxx/hadoop-3.3.3/bin/hdfs`(that is no such file).
Actually it should be `/home/student/student8/hadoop-3.3.3`

but I don't know how to change it.
anybody can help me? thank you so much

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`start-dfs.sh` runs SSH commands across each node in the cluster. As the error says, in `server3`, that path does not exist; it is not referring to local filesystem. Every server will need to download Hadoop binaries to a consistent location, and ideally that be in `/opt`, at least, and given some generic user permissions rather than under a specific user home directory with local user permissions.

You'll also want to set `HADOOP_HOME` and `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variables, such as in file under `/etc/profile.d/`.

Sidenote: You can use Apache Ambari and/or BigTop to configure a bare-metal Hadoop cluster with additional components.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  Maybe a consistent location is the key.